# Why don't work functions in callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First function (findOne) is working normal. But all Mongoose function in here callback just don't work without any errors. Why?
Thank you!

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Links = require('../models/Links');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/soft');

Links.findOne({}, function(err, l) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("1", l);
  Links.findOne({}, function(err, l_) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("2", l_);
  });
});

mongoose.connection.close();
```

Comment: `mongoose.connection.close();` is executed immediately after `Links.findOne({}, function(err, l) {...` (and most likely before it returns). You need to close the connection inside your last callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is closing the connection before the second `.find` has a chance to be called. Since `.find` is async the code executes the first call (which has a connection to execute with) but then continues on and disconnects before the first call returns to execute the second call.

Moving the `.close` call inside the second call will allow both calls to be made.

```
var Links = require('../models/Links');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/soft');

Links.findOne({}, function(err, l) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("1", l);
  Links.findOne({}, function(err, l_) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("2", l_);
    mongoose.connection.close();
  });
});
```